# Isometric grid coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm trying to do an isometric projection in HTML5 and the closest I can get is by scaling and rotating the viewport

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    class Point {
        constructor() {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
        }
    }
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    function tick(time) {
        ctx.save();

        ctx.translate(250,0);

        ctx.scale(1, 0.5);
        ctx.rotate(45 * Math.PI /180);
        let p = new Point();
        p.x = 4*32;
        p.y = 2*32;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fillRect(p.x,p.y,32,32);
        for (var x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {
            for (var y = 0; y < 10; ++y) {
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.strokeRect(x*32, y*32, 32, 32);
            }
        }

        ctx.restore();

        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

And it does work..but this isn't a practical solution because then when I try to draw isometric sprites within that scaled and rotated view, it looks really distorted. So I'd rather not go that route unless I can get it to work without distorting my sprites.

I also tried this website https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-isometric-worlds-primer-for-game-developers-updated--cms-28392

Which provided an equation for generating isometric grids. I used their cartesianToIsometric function to try and make an iso grid

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    class Point {
        constructor() {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
        }
    }
    let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    function cartesianToIsometric(cartPt) {
        var tempPt = new Point();
        tempPt.x = cartPt.x - cartPt.y;
        tempPt.y = (cartPt.x + cartPt.y) / 2;
        return (tempPt);
    }
    function tick(time) {

        for (var x = 0; x < 50; ++x) {
            for (var y = 0; y < 50; ++y) {
                let p = new Point();
                p.x = x * 32;
                p.y = y * 32;
                let iso = cartesianToIsometric(p);

                ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
                ctx.strokeRect(iso.x, iso.y, 32, 32);
            }
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(tick);
});
```

but it still looked wrong Unless I rotate or scale the viewport to correct it. [image]

So my question is..how can I draw an isometric grid without scaling and rotating my viewport(if possible)

If I have to scale my viewport like the first example, how can I do it without distorting my sprites.... Sorry if this question is confusing to read my knowledge on this is iffy..

Here's my html file
`index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are so close to the solution but a little bit confused. Let me explain:

Normally, you don't have to rotate and scale your canvas viewport. This is something you do when you create your isometric sprites. You should already have some isometric sprites and all you have to do just to put them in correct isometric coordinates.

Your second approach will do exactly what I mean, calculating the isometric points by using cartesian coordinates. It should work, no need to draw rectangles just place the images on the isometric coordinates.

The only trick here **you should place your isometric sprites from their bottom center points**:

```js
for (var x = 0; x < 50; ++x) {
    for (var y = 0; y < 50; ++y) {
        let p = new Point();
        p.x = x * 32;
        p.y = y * 32;
        let iso = cartesianToIsometric(p);

        // Apply offset to place each isometric image from its bottom center. 
        // The default pivot point (top left) won't do good 
        // because we need to stack them up according to their heights.
        let offset = {x: floorImageWidth/2, y: floorImageHeight}
        ctx.drawImage(floor, iso.x - offset.x, iso.y - offset.y);
    }
}
```

I also suggest using a **separate function to draw iso points** (not the rectangles) so that **you can debug your positions**:

```js
let debug = true;

function debugDraw(time) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 50; ++x) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 50; ++y) {
            let p = new Point();
            p.x = x * tileWidth;
            p.y = y * tileWidth;
            let iso = cartesianToIsometric(p);

            // draw pivot point for each tile
            ctx.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            ctx.fillRect(iso.x - 5, iso.y - 5, 10, 10);
        }
    }
}

if(debug){
    requestAnimationFrame(debugDraw)
}
```

Plus, here is a working demo for you to experiment further:
https://codepen.io/justintc/pen/eYpMabx

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: Oh I see! I guess I was trying to debug drawing rectangles but I see what you mean now. If I already have isometric sprites then I just need to use the math to get the iso coordinates instead of cartesian.. Thank you!

Comment: So if I have a sprite moving along the isometric map, would I just calculate it's x and y position from cartesian to isometric position using the cartesianToIsometric function?

Comment: Exactly, you can just increment the moving sprite's cartesian positions by a constant speed like `pos.x += 5` and convert them `cartesianToIsometric(pos)` before redrawing it into the canvas. I'm not very familiar with the vanilla canvas API, always used some libraries like Phaser.js, but I suppose you should clear the canvas context first somehow, then redraw it using `ctx.drawImage(sprite, iso.x, iso.y);` in your main game loop - the function works in every frame.

Comment: Thank you! And yes I'm supposed to clear the context with ctx.clearRect with size of canvas but I forgot to do it in the example code.

Comment: I have gotten it to work for the most part but something that still confuses me is , how do I move to the center/locate the center of an isometric tile? In simple 2d I could multiply the position by 32 on x and y..but how do I represent that in isometric?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do in 2d like as you said and use the `cartesianToIsometric()` method to translate it? For the entire map, I think the x and y values should be the count of tiles. Let's say 50/2 = 25 to find the position of center tile. After that you can do 25*32 for both x and y, then apply `cartesianToIsometric()` as I guess. Or, am I missing something you mean?

Comment: I think I realised what i was doing wrong and might have figured it out. If not I'll write up a test and show you an example :) Thank you so much though.

Comment: Even though my main focus was Java backend, I was so passionate about web-based games and developed some isometric ones which I really loved. It's been years though, but I'm glad I could still help :)